# Database structure for storing continuous changing value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Language: php, Database: mysql

Im making a mock stock website, so i have to save the changing values of a specific company overtime. Now im using cron job to run a script every hour to get current value and save it to database.

My question how shud i make structure of database for storing these values.

Point of concern: if the site runs for a year one company will generate 8544 values (365*24).

is it okay to keep it in one text field seperated by comma (23,56,34,65.....)

my current structure is 
id | name | current_value | changes

Comment: don't store anything in a comma separated list. It is a horrible practice. Just add a timestamp of when the row was inserted and add a new row every time. Then you can just select out the top row ordered by when descending. Databases can handle millions of rows, I doubt 8544 rows will cause a problem. And if it does become a problem, make a new table and archive old years.

Comment: If you keep things separated by commas, you are by definition - stupid. No insult intended, it's just that storing things into a relational database using comma separated values is a clear sign of lack of intellect. Store everything in a single row opposed to storing every value as a new record. Storing it as a new record lets you use the database to **query** and produce **results**. It's the same as if you stick every array element into a single index, instead into its own index. Also, the answer you accepted - it's wrong. Proper solution is what @JonathanKuhn wrote.

Comment: first ouch, second both @JonathanKuhn and the answer i have selected are saying same thing read again

Comment: I think the point N.B. is making is that you *could* use an auto_increment id, but it is better to use a timestamp column and doesn't add much (if any) overhead. The selected answer says this as well, but is primarily suggesting to just use an auto_increment id.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn hey just a small doubt new changes has caused 2,45,480 values to be created in a year in one table .. is it okay

Comment: Millions of rows is nothing to a database. If they get indexed the table should be pretty quick compared to combining multiple values in a single column. An index allows for quick lookups. Think about a dictionary. If you need a word that starts with "D", First thing you look for is the tab that says "D" and don't have to look at 98% of the book, just a few pages. If you need to find a single word from a string in a column, that would be like having a smaller dictionary, but you have to look at every word on every page to find one word. Every row needs to be looked at to find that one word.

Comment: And if you are worried that is still too many rows. Create a data retention policy and archive old data. For example, "at the beginning of the year we move all data from the previous year to an archive table named `{tableName}_archive_{year}`" and then your table contains only new data. You can even consolidate and just keep a count of changes for reporting. "in september-2014 we had NN changes of type XX".

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Thank you so much.People like you make this site what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> id | name | current_value | changes

Should be a sutable structure. 
Make your id a primary index and auto incrementing, then you get the correct order by order by id desc.

An other solution would be to add a timestamp field as described above. That should have the same functionality with the added feature that you can see at a later time EXACTLY what time that value was generated!

Comment: actually changes stores all changes to that specific company in comma separated form, but i got what you are saying. Thank you for help.